# When saving, how to fix "set" method to update an entry. after add form validation on controllers

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

after add form validation in my controllers

```
public function save($id_kecamatan='')
    {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_kecamatan','nama_kecamatan', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE){
            $data = [
                'nama_kecamatan' => $this->input->post('nama_kecamatan')
            ];
        }
        $simpan = $this->KecamatanModel->saveKecamatan($data);
        redirect('admin/kecamatan/add');
    }
```

this is my model, on the line $this->db->insert

```
public function saveKecamatan($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('tbl_kecamatan', $data);
        $id_kecamatan = $this->db->insert_id();
        return true;
    }
```

my view, when submit, appear You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

```
<?= validation_errors(); ?>
<form action="<?= site_url('admin/kecamatan/save');?>" method="POST">
    <div class="box-body">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Kecamatan</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_kecamatan" id="" placeholder="Nama Kecamatan">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <input type="hidden" name="id_kecamatan" value="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Simpan</button>
      <a href="<?= site_url('admin/kecamatan');?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i> Batal</a>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: whats the question ?

Comment: how to fix You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Comment: @munawarhusein `$data` is defined inside if condition and hence unknown outside,so you haven't send any data to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation is useless because it will not prevent empty value to be passed to
`$this->db->insert('tbl_kecamatan', $data)`.

Try to prevent empty value by moving `$simpan` variable one line up :

```
public function save($id_kecamatan='')
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama_kecamatan','nama_kecamatan', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE){
        $data = [
            'nama_kecamatan' => $this->input->post('nama_kecamatan')
        ];
        $simpan = $this->KecamatanModel->saveKecamatan($data);
    }
    redirect('admin/kecamatan/add');
}
```